# How to build node.js / react.js backend for multiuser apps

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hey guys after all these year I can finally get into node.js and react.js so i'm a total beginner.

My first project will be to migrate a time booking system for our production from the current Qt C++ application to a web application.

The biggest issues at this point is to decide how to build the backend.

The application needs to handle several concurrent users with full duplex communication between the client sides.

The closes example would be a system like Trello. So a collaborative system where multiple users are able to move tasks around.
Once a user moves a task from one spot to another i have to instantly reorganize the tasks for every currently logged in user. So i can guarantee that everyone is up to date at any point in time.

How would you build this and what libraries are best suited for this case?

I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

greets

Comment: I think you have to use something like socket.io to get new changes and do them for all clients...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use websocket to keep server and client side in touch.
To prevent operation conflict, you need to

1. lock the task/resource when user start doing edit/move, and inform other clients that it has been locked.
2. write result into db/nosql.
3. inform all other user client change result and get ACK response.
4. release the lock and inform all clients.

to smooth the process, release lock when getting the very first ACK.
A change log with timestamp (monotonic time) might be helpful to prevent conflict.

Besides, Electron (based on NodeJs) is suitable for building client side as an alternative to Qt.